# Linking Google Optimize Container to Google Analytics 4 Property

Tags: google-analytics, google-optimize

I'm trying to setup a Google Optimize Container for A/B testing + other.  The issue I'm having is that I definitely need to link to Google Analytics in order to measure results.  When I try and link to a Google Analytics property for this only the Universal Analytics properties I have (which I don't actually use) show up, but not the Google Analytics 4 property I'm actually using.  Am I doing something wrong?  Is the connection not actually implemented yet by Google?

TL;DR: Google Analytics 4 Properties don't show up as linkable in Google Optimize Container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE 2021/04/06:

Trying to link it in Google Optimize says `Coming Soon`.  Looks like we just have to wait.

Comment: I got this: "Google Optimize doesn't currently support Google Analytics 4 properties, but we're working on it and we'll have more to share later this year. Thanks for your patience."

Answer (score 7):

follow this step:

create a new property in. google analytics

---

Click on show advance

Activ Create a Universal Analytics property

Add your website address

Create both a Google Analytics 4 and a Universal Analytics property

---

Comment: Thanks I think that's definitely a work-around for some people so it should be visible.  I was specifically looking for the link to GA4 so I'm still waiting.

Answer (score 3):

GA4 is not supported. As of right now you can't link a GA4 property to Google Optimize.

GA4 is not on this list https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/6315871?hl=en

This thread: https://support.google.com/optimize/thread/80704065?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around this issue by adding an additional property to my GA4 account.  You have the option during the creation process of the GA4 account to provide support for both GA4 and universal analytics.  You can also add the support after the fact as well... just go into your admin section of Google Analytics and create a new property.  After that, you will be able to connect Google Optimize and your GA4 account.

Comment: Ok thanks I"ll try this when I have time and then I'll update the question with the results.

Comment: @Kenneth Durrum, how do you add a UA tag to an existing GA4 property? Have tried looking everywhere to find.

Comment: @Jake232 this is exactly the problem I'm having as well.

Comment: So as an update I tried the same as @Jake232 and couldn't manage to create a UA tag from an existing GA4 property.

Comment: If this answer is suggesting that you make a UA property in addition to a GA4 property, this is not a solution at all.

Answer (score 1):

I believe ***@Kenneth Durrum*** was referring to creating a "Universal Analytics property" instead of a GA4 property. You can also create both as mentioned by ***@mohammad hossin rouhani***, but Google Optimize will only work for the Universal property. Please refer tho the image below for selecting the Universal property on Admin console. (**Added this as an answer since i was not able to attach the image on Kenneth's comments**).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Gsuite, make sure your accounts are linked go to
https://marketingplatform.google.com/ and under Administration, link the accounts.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new Universal Analytics property, you can link it to your existing GA4 property under Admin > GA4 Setup Assistant